# Prove that $ \sqrt[100]{1,1}>1,0009$

Tags: inequality

As I am looking for an "middle/high school" solution I tried to use AM-GM to crack that inequality, but none of my approaches were successful. The inequality is equivalent to
$$ 11 \times 10000^{100}>10 \times 10009^{100}$$ It confuses me how could it be solved by simple estimating RHS by lower numbers since base of RHS is bigger than base of LHS.

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd suggest writing the binomial expansion of $(1+0.0009)^{100}$, and comparing it with the series $1+0.09+0.09^2+0.09^3+\cdots = \frac{1}{1-0.09} < 1.1$.

Comment: What does $\sqrt[100]{1,1}$ mean? I’ve never seen that notation before.

Comment: @tparker FYI, in some regions, a comma is used as a [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) instead of a period. Thus, it's equivalent to $\sqrt[100]{1.1}$, i.e., the $100$'th root of $1.1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. How can we manipulate that into something that we can AM-GM?

Wishful thinking: In AM-GM, the AM side is "some term raised to a power", and the GM side is "product of some terms". It seems like we have the GM side, but not exactly the AM side.
**What can we do to force out the AM side?** IE How can we make $ 11 \times 10000^{100}$ look like "some term raised to a power"?

Hint / One possible approach:

> Divide both sides by 11. The LHS is now a term raised to some power.

> However, how many terms are we using? On the LHS, with $10000^{100}$, it seems like we want 100 terms. On the RHS, with $\frac{10}{11} \times 10009^{100}$, it seems like we want $1+100=101$ terms.

> Also, the inequality is pretty tight since $\sqrt[100]{1.1} \approx 1.0009536\ldots $ from Wolfram. This suggests that we need to introduce 1 more term, that will make $\frac{10}{11}$ closer to 10009.

> We do so by multiplying by 10000, which makes the LHS $10000^{101}$, still a "term raised to a power".

---

Applying the hint, we want to show that

$$ 10000^{101} > \frac{ 100000 } { 11} \times 10009^{100}.$$

This is true because:

$\begin{array} { l l l  } \frac{ 100000 } { 11} \times 10009^{100} & < ( \frac{\frac{100000}{11} + 10009 \times 100}{101}) ^ {101} \quad & \text{by AM-GM} \\     
& < 10000 ^ { 101} \quad  & \text{by calculating the base} \end{array}$

---

Notes:

- It's not immediately obvious what could work, so one has to try various approaches.
- EG If we divided throughout by 11 to get LHS = $ 10000^{100}$, are we still able to AM-GM our way out? Note that the power indicates the (weighted) number of terms.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) in the form
$$(1 - x)^t \geqslant 1 - xt$$
where $t \geqslant 1$ and $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, we obtain
$$11(10000)^{100} = 11(10009 - 9)^{100} = 11(10009)^{100} \bigg(1 - \dfrac{9}{10009}\bigg)^{100} \geqslant 11(10009)^{100} \bigg(1 - \frac{100\cdot 9}{10009}\bigg).$$
But $$11\cdot \bigg(1 - \frac{100\cdot 9}{10009}\bigg) = \frac{100199}{10009} > 10.$$
Hence, we conclude that
$$11(10000)^{100} > 10(10009)^{100},$$
which as the OP has noted, is equivalent to
$$\sqrt[100]{1.1} > 1.0009.$$

Comment: @Gribouillis:  I have fixed my proof.  Thank you for pointing out the error in an earlier version of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When $u\ge0$ we have $u-\frac{u^2}{2}\le\log(1+u)\le  u$, hence
\begin{equation}
\log(1.0009)\le 0.0009< 0.00095 = 0.001 - \frac{0.0001}{2} = 10^{-2}(10^{-1}- \frac{10^{-2}}{2})\le 10^{-2}\log(1.1)
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
1.0009 < 1.1^{0.01}
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm not sure that your lemma is widely known among high schoolers.

Comment: They can prove it by studying the functions $f(u) = \log(1+u)- u$ and $g(u)=\log(1+u)-u+u^2/2$

Comment: @Grilbouillis Since amount of skills required from high schoolers around the world may vary I also added "middle schoolers". What I meant is that solution should demand creativity and involve only elementary ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure AM-GM is that much more elementary. I confess that I don't see a more creative solution. The usual tools to handle exotic exponents are the exponential function and the logarithm.

Comment: @Gribouillis There is an elementary AM-GM approach (EG see my solution). It might not be obvious how one can find it through.